# QR/Barcode alternatives for a mobile site?

Tags: barcode, qr-code

I'm looking for an alternative to QR and barcodes for a user verification functionality. Here's how the application works: A vendor accepts bids from its customers and selects a winner. The winner is given a token to present to the vendor in person to receive the service. We'd prefer not to use QR or barcodes that will require an external app or scanning device. The solution is for a mobile site (otherwise we'd use Bluetooth LE in iOS 7, for example).

Comment: What vendor is supposed to do when customer presents a barcode?

Comment: The vendor admin would verify the user's identity by scanning the barcode, but I'm looking for an alternative user verification method.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish that is sending (via email, text message, screen notification) the same secret token to both the vendor and the customer.

If it is something reasonably short (like TF57S4T3), verification can be done visually.

If big volumes are expected, you can encode the same code as QR or Barcode and provide a website or app for automatic verification as a commodity for the vendor.